# nodemailer with XOauth2 settings says bad credentials

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, nodemailer

I have the following node code:

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var xoauth2 = require('xoauth2');
/*
    Here we are configuring our SMTP Server details.
    STMP is mail server which is responsible for sending and recieving email.
*/
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    auth: {
        XOAuth2: {
            user: "buckscountytourofhonor@gmail.com",
            pass: "****",
            clientId:"myclientidenteredhere",
            clientSecret:"mysecretenteredhere",
            refreshToken:"mytokenenteredhere"
        }

    }
});
module.exports = function(app, passport){

    app.get('/send',function(req,res){
        var mailOptions={
            to : 'buckscountytourofhonor@gmail.com',
            from: req.query.email,
            subject : req.query.subject,
            text : req.query.name +": "+req.query.message
        }
        console.log(mailOptions);
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
                res.end("error");
            }else{
                console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
                res.end("sent");
            }
        });
    });
```

I am currently following [this](http://masashi-k.blogspot.com/2013/06/sending-mail-with-gmail-using-xoauth2.html) tutorial. Actually followed many, but this is the most succinct.

I am getting the following error:

> Error: invalid login: 535-5.7.8 username and password not accepted

Can anyone help me figure out what I am missing, I have been spending over 3 hours researching this.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have faced this issue just now. I have an older implementation working just fine with xoauth, another app with the same code but a more recent nodemailer install did give

> Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

I went from xoauth2 like so

```
var generator = require('xoauth2').createXOAuth2Generator({
                                user: 'xxx',
                                clientId: 'xxx',
                                clientSecret: 'xxx',
                                refreshToken: 'xxx'
                            });
```

and

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(({
                                service: 'gmail',
                                auth: {
                                    xoauth2: generator
                                }
```

to

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(({
                                service: 'gmail',
                                auth: {
                                    type: 'OAuth2',
                                    user: 'xxx',
                                    clientId: 'xxx',
                                    clientSecret: 'xxx',
                                    refreshToken: 'xxxx'
                                }
                            }));
```

This was then working for me. Not sure if thats it but worth a try. I did follow the same tutorial for the Gmail-setup, this did work in my earlier implementation and again with the new project.

Comment: Where can I  get the

 user: 'xxx',
                                    clientId: 'xxx',
                                    clientSecret: 'xxx',
                                    refreshToken: 'xxxx'

?

Comment: in my case via the Google Developer Console, there are some guides out there, just one [link](https://medium.com/@nickroach_50526/sending-emails-with-node-js-using-smtp-gmail-and-oauth2-316fe9c790a1)

Comment: How can we automatically get refresh token instead of manually setup refresh token via Console. ?

Comment: sorry can't answer that; I only need one fixed refresh token for the XOAuth2. I do use different tokens for the user interaction, I generate those through `crypto.randomBytes`